# Change mouse cursor over widget

Tags: python, wxpython

How can I make the mouse cursor change over a particular widget on my `wx.Panel`?

In the following example, I want to let the cursor change to a hand when it is over `bmp2`, the image on the upper right, but it stays an arrow. Curious to me is also that if I replace `bmp2.SetCursor` by `bmp4.SetCursor` then suddenly the cursor is a hand everywhere.

```
import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        gs = wx.GridSizer(2, 2, 5, 5)

        bmp1 = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyBitmap(150, 150))
        bmp2 = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyBitmap(150, 150))
        bmp3 = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyBitmap(150, 150))
        bmp4 = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyBitmap(150, 150))

        gs.Add(bmp1, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        gs.Add(bmp2, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        gs.Add(bmp3, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        gs.Add(bmp4, 0, wx.EXPAND)

        bmp2.SetCursor(wx.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_HAND))

        self.panel.SetSizer(gs) 
        gs.Fit(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    Example(None).Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Have you tried catching the `EVT_ENTER_WINDOW` and `EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW` events on `bmp2` and setting the cursor through that?

Comment: After actually testing your code, my cursor changes to a hand when over `bmp2`. What OS/wxPython versions are you using?

Comment: @dpwilson I'm on Ubuntu Linux with wxpython version 2.8.12.1 (gtk2-unicode). For using the enter/leave events, I'd still have to find out a reliable way to set the cursor in general. The fact that it works for `bmp4.SetCursor` but not for `self.SetCursor` nor `self.panel.SetCursor` (at least on my system) makes it confusing for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out that I can avoid the problem on my platform (Linux) by wrapping each widget into its own panel.

Replace the eight lines that create the static bitmaps and add them to the grid sizer by:

```
    p1 = wx.Panel(self.panel)
    p2 = wx.Panel(self.panel)
    p3 = wx.Panel(self.panel)
    p4 = wx.Panel(self.panel)
    bmp1 = wx.StaticBitmap(p1, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyBitmap(150, 150))
    bmp2 = wx.StaticBitmap(p2, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyBitmap(150, 150))
    bmp3 = wx.StaticBitmap(p3, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyBitmap(150, 150))
    bmp4 = wx.StaticBitmap(p4, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyBitmap(150, 150))

    gs.Add(p1, 0, wx.EXPAND)
    gs.Add(p2, 0, wx.EXPAND)
    gs.Add(p3, 0, wx.EXPAND)
    gs.Add(p4, 0, wx.EXPAND)
```